# Method that checks if one word is a rotation of another

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

Working on the Cracking The Coding Interview problem that asks for a method that checks if one string is a rotation of another. The one caveat to the problem is that it must be solved with a single call to `isSubstring(s1, s2)`.

I fully understand the author's solution that says-- if s2 is a rotation of s1, then you can break s1 into two parts x and y such that s1 = xy and s2 = yx. The author continues to say, therefore, that s2 must be a substring of s1s1 (yx is a part of xyxy).

I'm writing this question to make sure I'm understanding thoroughly. Isn't it equivalent to say that s1 must be a substring of s2s2 (that is, xy must be a substring of yxyx) for s2 to be a rotation? And in that way, both approaches are equivalent? Not sure if I'm missing something..

Comment: A reference to a problem on an external site that is not even linked and only described in such a vague way as you did isn't helpful. Please edit with a description of the actual problem (link is optional and should only be provided in addition to a description of the problem).

Comment: The question is only two sentences in the book that it came from, so there's really not a lot more to add to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two are equivalent. If `s1` is a rotation of `s2`, then `s2` is also a rotation of `s1`, so it doesn't matter which direction you approach the problem from. `s1` will be a substring of `s2s2` and `s2` will be a substring of `s1s1` if the two strings are rotations of each other.